# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Have already allocated a maximum of 8192 pages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I am running my pyspark jobs, getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Have already allocated a maximum of 8192 pages
```

Any idea what might cause it?

Comment: Same issue here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed it by reducing number partitions/tasks (spark.sql.shuffle.partitions)